# How to store user data in a Next.js application without compromising SSR/SSG principles?

Tags: next.js

With all the buzz around SSR and SSG in Next.js, I have a question about how to store user data (such as id, name, etc.) in a secure and efficient manner. Often, there are personal libraries where users store items like articles that they have added to their favorites. I need to be able to show these items as favorites on a listing page.

Can someone with expertise in Next.js guide me on how to organize a store with user data that doesn't compromise the SSR/SSG principles? I would like to avoid making too many requests and ensure the security of the user's data.

One idea I had was to make a conditional "getMe" request to the server with a token to fetch the user's data. However, this would result in a large number of requests. On the other hand, storing user data in localStorage in plain text is not secure.